# Installing Opus Fails

Tags: homebrew

I already have opus installed, but I installed it a couple years ago before they supported ARM64 and when I try to update it so that it is using the ARM64 architecture, I get the following error:

Input:

```
brew reinstall opus
```

Output:

```
==> Fetching libav
==> Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/formula-patches/e07f287/libav/remove_unconditional_X11_probe.patch
Already downloaded: /Users/ricardo/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/c0cf441a3ebfdcda6aff116e0f09600cd3240d9e673349bdc7958273c26f2405--remove_unconditional_X11_probe.patch
==> Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/formula-patches/b6e917c/libav/Check-for--no_weak_imports-in-ldflags-on-macOS.patch
Already downloaded: /Users/ricardo/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/65bb038c609540ca6c37bea67eae3bf1e772c850b92d6572125df19577626406--Check-for--no_weak_imports-in-ldflags-on-macOS.patch
==> Downloading https://github.com/libav/libav/commit/c6558e8840fbb2386bf8742e4d68dd6e067d262e.patch?full_index=1
Already downloaded: /Users/ricardo/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/84f5e0a2ee566e9722e0b8f16fedee41b1e92c8f5b050f3f1bda27f33f1026d1--c6558e8840fbb2386bf8742e4d68dd6e067d262e.patch
==> Downloading https://github.com/libav/libav/commit/141c960e21d2860e354f9b90df136184dd00a9a8.patch?full_index=1
Already downloaded: /Users/ricardo/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/e3f9af21edcc9cf8c22e1e5039a87643affdea084802195fad0406438a3c6d6e--141c960e21d2860e354f9b90df136184dd00a9a8.patch
Error: Failed to download resource "libav"
Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/curl --disable --cookie /dev/null --globoff --show-error --user-agent Homebrew/4.1.6\ \(Macintosh\;\ arm64\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 13.4.1\)\ curl/7.88.1 --header Accept-Language:\ en --retry 3 --fail --location --silent --head https://libav.org/releases/libav-12.3.tar.xz` exited with 6. Here's the output:
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: libav.org
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: libav.org
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: libav.org
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: libav.org
```

It appears as though libav is unresponsive. From my understanding, libav is no longer supported, but I can't get past it because it is a requirement for the brew install.